# Need help with drop down list on the profile

Tags: customization, profiles

Instead of text I need to display image. User will choose Male or Female from drop down list in the user profile and the image of my choice (different for female and different for male) will display on front end. Right now on front-end it displays text "Female" or "Male". How to modify it?

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'custom_user_fields' ); add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'custom_user_fields' ); add_action( "user_new_form", "custom_user_fields" ); function custom_user_fields( $user )  {  $user_fb_link = get_the_author_meta( 'user_fb_link', $user->ID);    $user_gender = get_the_author_meta( 'user_gender', $user->ID); ?>   <h3><?php _e("Custom User information", "blank"); ?></h3>   <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="user_gender"><?php _e("Gender"); ?></label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <select name="user_gender" id="user_gender" style="width:180px">
                <option value="">-Select Gender-</option>
                <option value="male"   <?php selected( $user_gender, "male"); ?>>Male</option>
                <option value="female" <?php selected( $user_gender, "female"); ?>>Female</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="user_fb_link"><?php _e("Enter Your Fb Link"); ?></label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="user_fb_link" id="user_fb_link" size="60" value="<?php echo $user_fb_link;?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>

</table> <?php  } add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_custom_user_fields' ); add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_custom_user_fields' ); add_action( 'user_register', 'save_custom_user_fields' ); function save_custom_user_fields( $user_id )  {    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { return false; }     update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_gender', $_POST['user_gender'] );     update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_fb_link', $_POST['user_fb_link'] ); }
```

Comment: you forget the non-binary gender XD. to have dropdown list with pictures try that : https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render

Comment: No, I don't need drop down list with pictures. That's not what I'm asking. The drop down list can be just text. I want outcome as images.

Comment: Or maybe if it's easier it can be 3 avatars to choose with radio button and that avatar chosen by the user will display. But without ability for a user to upload their own.

Comment: or it could be the flag thing. Choose USA, CANADA, CHINA. and when user chooses it will display a flag on their profile.

Comment: So the dropdown is already working? So the only thing you need is to display the selection on the front end?

Comment: swisspidy: yes, drop down is working, and it displays text now. I use short code "gender' to display text. The only thing I need is image instead of text on front-end.